# Text centering in a circle

Tags: composition

I'm designing a labeled circle and so far it's been a struggle of finding the perfect vertical position for a one letter label.

Currently I have two options.

[image]

Which one *seems* better centered?

Comment: The one on the left, anyway your letter A is extreme in this visual alignment if youd put B in the image your result might be different.   :) Yes you can not just win.

Comment: The key point of contention for me is the horizontal line in A. On the left it's dead center every which way, but since the top/bottom parts are not proportional it seems off. Thanks for the input @joojaa :)

Comment: Experiment with several different letters. You can't base your decision on a dataset of 1.

Comment: "Bilbo" definitely looks, and most likely is actually centered. You're just being visually disappointed with the letter "A" in the particular font you are using. Stick with the actual center of the circle so that it is consistent regardless of the interior content.